# "in" keyword not working properly when used with object.value in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I need to execute some code. But my code is not working properly. I have made an simple example to demonstrate the malfunction.

When I run

```
console.log("val" in Object.values({key:"val"})); //returns false
```

It gives me false. But if I run

```
console.log(Object.values({key:"val"}))
```

outputs => `['val']`

I don't understand if it is supposed to work like this. If yes. Why ?

Thanks in Advance.....:)

Answer (score 1):

MDN says "the in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain.", `Object.values` returns an array. To check if an item exists in an array, use the [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method.

```js
console.log(
  Object.values({key:"val"}).includes("val")
); // Returns true
```